# cordova build error: SDK "iphoneos6.0" cannot be located

Tags: iphone, xcode, cordova, build-error, ios6.0

i developing a html5-App for Android and iOS. Building for Android and iOS-Simulator works like a charm. But if i want to build the app for iOS-Device the build process stops with following error:

update-ios:
cordova prepare ios
build-ios-xcodebuild:
xcodebuild: error: SDK "iphoneos6.0" cannot be located.
/Users/.../nbproject/build.xml:178: exec returned: 64

For development i using netbeansIDE, xcode 5.1.1 and cordova 3.5.

Also i downloaded the iOS 6.1 sdk and copied into sdk folder of xcode, but that don't work for me. May i have to set an environment variable?

Is there someone, who could give me a hint?

In advance